# Spring mongodb dbref property null?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm using spring mongodb. I have below entities.

```
@Document
public class Organization implements Serializable{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -375519278304469728L;

    //id will be used for storing MongoDB _id
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String orgId;
    private String name;
    private String description;
//getters and setters

}
```

---

```
@Document
public class OrgInstanceDetails implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3508307831786555144L;

    @Id
    private String id;
    @DBRef
    private Organization organization;

    private String instanceName;
    private String accessKeyId;
    private String secretKey;
//getters and setters

}
```

I have below method:

```
@Override
    public List<OrgInstanceDetails> getAllOrgsDetails() {
        return mongoOps.findAll(OrgInstanceDetails.class,"OrgInstanceDetails");
    }
```

Above method returns the results. But `DBRef` property value is null. Why am not getting `Organization` details along with `OrgInstanceDetails` ?

Comment: Could you show as your main method or an example with the inserts? and the json that has been inserted in your DB.